# Why don't electronic thermometers "move back"?

Tags: temperature, thermometer

I have noticed since a long time that electronic thermometers, which use a temperature sensor at their tip to measure temperature, only move forwards, i.e. their reading only increases as they measure the temperature.

Ideally, their reading increases until it reaches the actual temperature and then it stays still for a moment (waiting for further change) and finally gives the temperature (after a beep).

However, while the reading is increasing, if I immediately put the thermometer's tip at a cooler place (with temperature lower than current reading), the reading stops where it is and I get the beep.

Why does the thermometer just *stop* when I reduce the temperature during the measurement? Why doesn't the reading descrease to the new, cooler temperature? Does it have to do anything with the temperature sensor?

Comment: Do you specifically mean a thermometer meant to measure human body temperature?

Comment: @Justme yes, you are right.

Comment: Sounds like a peak hold function in the electronics, not a property of the sensor.

Answer (score 10):

The action of the digital clinical thermometer is designed to hold the peak reading so that it can be read at leisure by the user. This was actually a feature of the classic mercury thermometer and is replicated by the digital thermometer firmware.

[image]

> To use the thermometer, the bulb is placed in the location where the temperature is to be measured and left long enough to be certain to reach thermal equilibrium—typically three minutes. Maximum-reading is achieved by means of a constriction in the neck close to the bulb. As the temperature of the bulb rises, the liquid expands up the tube through the constriction.
>
> **When the temperature falls, the column of liquid breaks at the constriction and cannot return to the bulb, thus remaining stationary in the tube.** After reading the value, the thermometer must be reset by repeatedly swinging it sharply to shake the liquid back through the constriction. Source: [Medical thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_thermometer#Liquid-filled). Emphasis mine.*

Note that the mercury thermometer is evacuated (a vacuum) so there is no air pressure to push the mercury back into the bulb. When the bulb cooled the mercury column broke at the constriction and there was vacuum at both sides of the thin column of mercury on the scaled portion of the instrument. A centrifugal shake (bulb outermost) returned the mercury to the bulb.

Answer (score 6):

The electronic thermometer you are using is for a specific purpose, measuring human temperature, and it tries to emulate the operation of a similar non-electronic thermometer. It is not a general purpose thermal measuring device.

The old-school thermometer keeps its previous measurement and must be manually reset with rapid hand movements. Then you either keep it for 10 minutes in your armpit or mouth or whatever and assume the measurement is done, or you look at it and determine that the temperature does not rise any more, so it has reached the measurement value, and the reading stays there until manually reset again.

The the electronic thermometer starts at room temperature, and when you use it to measure body temperature, it starts to heat up and since there is no point continuing the measurement if it has reached the point where temperature is not rising any more, so the measurement is complete and it notifies you with a beep.

So it has been just programmed to stop when temperature does not rise any more.
It is not a general purpose measuring device.

Comment: I understand why it stops and waits. But why does it not move backwards?

Comment: @MrigankPawagi Because they programmed that way so you don't lose the reading if you are fiddling around when it is sitting in your armpit, and certainly not when you pull it out of your armpit into the cool air to read it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not about the sensor. Device's purpose is to show the maximum temperature it has measured, that is because user's purpose is to measure the body temperature as exact as possible. Body's temperature is supposed to be stable along the measurement process, so the measurement difference in time will converge to zero.

When sensor is kept on one place and remained for the thermal equilibrum, it may not possible to keep it very consistent, so you may choose to account the most valid result measured, this is possible if it shows the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

The thermometer almost surely is stopping the measurement because of software, not a 'hardware' thing.  The tip IS cooling, and the computer inside IS "seeing" this, but it's program tells it to stop the reading.  It's a medical device .. If you want a similar thermometer that doesn't do this, get a  cooking thermometer maybe.

If I were to program the thermometer, I would instruct it to watch the temperature rise until it leveled-off.  The assumption is that would be around 100F (38C), body temperature.   I'd take a reading every 1/2 second or so, and when they stopped changing within maybe 0.01 degrees for a couple seconds, I'd BEEP and say it was done. I'd maybe also stop the reading and BEEP if I saw the temperature start to drop again.

Comment: Okay, so that means this is completely a software issue. Do you know of any particular Reason why medical thermometers work in this manner?

Comment: @MrigankPawagi: A medical thermometer works this way so that you can take it out of the patient's mouth and read it at your leisure without losing the maximum temperature reading.  If the patient has a fever you don't want to lose that information because the thermometer is now falling towards room temperature.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned that this is a feature specific to medical thermometers and simulates the function of mercury *medical* thermometers, but not the actual clinical reason for this.

The reason that medical thermometers "err" on the side of reading higher than lower is that a clinically significant elevated temperature (fever) is a *much* more commonly encountered situation than the opposite, and fevers are not always obvious when looking at a person. If the thermometer detects signs of a *possible* fever by reading "high", then a clinician can perform a more thorough investigation to verify the reading and determine if any treatment is needed. When a person has an actual body temperature that is problematically low, this is called [hypothermia](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hypothermia/symptoms-causes/syc-20352682), which tends to have obvious signs. When someone has ice-cold skin, slurred speech, shallow breathing, and a faint pulse, it doesn't take a thermometer reading to know they are in hypothermia.

In a nutshell, medical thermometers are designed to screen patients for fever, not hypothermia.

Comment: "*The reason that medical thermometers "err" on the side of reading higher than lower ...*" The clinical thermometer should not err. It's simply a peak hold function so that the reading is held for long enough that it doesn't droop in the period between removal from the body and the display being read. It will only work if the ambient temperature is less than body temperature.